# Why does Number() return wrong values with very large integers?

Tags: javascript

Number() function returns incorrect values on some arguments, like this:

```
Number('10000000712224641') returns 10000000712224640
Number('10000000544563531') returns 10000000544563532
```

I tested this on Firefox, Chome, IE and Node.js. Why is this happening?

Comment: Betting on floating point precision.

Comment: JavaScript (as well as every other programming language) have [well documented examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) of problems like this.

Comment: @JuanMendes Aren't all numbers in JS stored the same way?

Comment: @JuanMendes: It certainly looks like floating point precision to me. Overflow would lead to values becoming negative or otherwise *wildly* wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet The first time John Skeet has said something to me... Reviewed my answer to explain that some integers above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` can be expressed and yes, it is because of precision

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Javascript uses 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point to store all numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) - like `double` in C# and Java, for example. There isn't a different type to store integers. (The actual implementation may use optimizations to avoid always performing arithmetic in this way, but from an end-user perspective the results will always be *as if* every number were treated as a 64-bit binary floating point value.)

That means only 52 bits are available to store the significand, with the other bits being used for the exponent and sign. With normalization, that means you can effectively store values with 53 significant bits of precision. That means beyond 2<sup>53</sup>-1 (which is the value 9007199254740991 as quoted in other answers), the distance between "adjacent" numbers is more than 1, so you can't store all integers exactly.

Comment: "There isn't a different type to store integers." - not at the engine level. V8, at least, has a dedicated `Smi` type for small integers (31 bits). So something like `x = 3 + 2` will not involve doubles internally.

Comment: @georg: I was going by the only Javascript specification I could find, which was the old ECMA-262 one (ECMAscript rather than JS...) Additional pointers welcome :) Is that optimization ever visible to users, or can they always treat numbers as if they *were* always stored as 64-bit IEEE-754?

Comment: It's totally transparent, it's not possible for a JS program to distinguish between a SMI (immediate) and a double, heap-allocated number. And ECMAscript is (the official dialect of) JS, the 2015 spec is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type).

Comment: @georg: Good. Glad it's just an implementation detail :)

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript safely supports approximately up to 17 digits and all numbers, whether floats or integers, are expressed in 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating.

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // 9007199254740991
```

When you get above that number, the trailing digits get rounded unless you have a power of 2 (or the addition of powers of two)

```
 Math.pow(2, 54)     // 18014398509481984 (not rounded)
 Math.pow(2, 54) + 1 // 18014398509481984 (rounded)
 Math.pow(2, 54) - 1 // 18014398509481984 (rounded)
 Math.pow(2,57) + Math.pow(2,52) // 148618787703226370 (not rounded)
 Math.pow(2, 57) + Math.pow(2, 52) + 1 // 148618787703226370 (rounded)
```

Comment: It's not a matter of exact powers of 2... it's just that there are 53 bits of precision (assuming a normalized number). So any integers which only *need* 53 bits in the significand (and are within the right range of exponents) can be expressed exactly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to understand how `Math.pow(2,54)` seems to work, and all the `Math.pow(2,54) -1 === Math.pow(2,54)` and `Math.pow(2,54) + 1  === Math.pow(2,54)`

Comment: Think about what the binary representation of 2^54+1 is, when you've only got 53 significant bits to play with. The closest exactly-representable value to that is... 2^54.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm still trying to follow what you mean, I said that powers of 2 can be expressed precisely even if larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and other numbers can't. How is that different from what you said?

Comment: Consider 2^54 + 2^52. That's not a power of 2, which means according to your rule that it can't be expressed precisely - but actually it can, because it doesn't need more than 53 significant digits to represent it exactly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Does the answer look accurate now?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that javascript supports a number of digits. The maximum safe integer possible is stored in a constant called MAX_SAFE_INTEGER which contains value 9007199254740991.