# Convert neo4j Integer object to JavaScript integer

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am storing `dateBirth` as milliseconds in neo4j.

When using the browser I get this:

```
match (u:User) return u.dateBirth // Returns -2209078800000
```

When using the bolt driver (neo4j v3-javascript) I get this:

```
match (u:User) return toInt(u.dateBirth) as dateBirth
// Returns: Integer { low: -1465609856, high: -515 }
```

How do I convert this Integer Object to a primitive number in JavaScript?

Comment: What happends if you use `toFloat` instead of `toInt`?

Comment: There is a documentation about integers in the driver's readme https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#write-integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Number() return wrong values with very large integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727608/why-does-number-return-wrong-values-with-very-large-integers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [readme](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type):

> The Neo4j type system includes 64-bit integer values. However, Javascript can only safely represent integers between -(2^53 - 1) and (2^53 - 1). In order to support the full Neo4j type system, the driver includes an explicit Integer types. Any time the driver receives an Integer value from Neo4j, it will be represented with the Integer type by the driver.

You can use `toInt()` (assuming a 32 bit integer) or `toNumber()` to the convert to the nearest floating point JavaScript Number type.

The detailed docs on the `Integer` type are available [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/integer.js~Integer.html).

Comment: using toFloat() instead of toInt() worked.


`match (u:User) return toFloat(u.dateBirth) as dateBirth`

This link was very useful. Where did you find that?
http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/integer.js~Integer.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function found in [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/180). Works great so far!

```js
function toNumber({ low, high }) {
  let res = high

  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    res *= 2
  }

  return low + res
}
```