# Why using the count function in neo4j with graphql returns two values ​called low and high?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, graphql, neo4j-graphql-js

If I execute the following cypher in Neo4j browser returns the expected values

```
MATCH (n:Document)
RETURN { 
    year: n.year ,
    countdocs : COUNT(n) 
}
```

Result:

```
{"countdocs":3,"year":"2018"}
```

But If I execute the same cypher in neo4j-graphql

```
type Query {
    totalActivityOverTime: [JSONObject] @cypher(statement: """
       MATCH (n:Document)
        RETURN { 
         year: n.year ,
         countdocs : COUNT(n) 
       }
    """) 
}
```

returns :

```
  {
    "countdocs": {
      "low": 3,
      "high": 0
    },
    "year": "2018"
  },
```

What means the values ​​low and high?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert neo4j Integer object to JavaScript integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038019/convert-neo4j-integer-object-to-javascript-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the type of `countdocs`. As far as I know, if you define 'countdocs' as `BigInt` in neo4j-graphql, it returns a dict with {"low": Int, "high": Int} in order to represent 64bit integers. Define `countdocs` as `Int` in the schema should resolve the issue.
`Int` type supports up to 53-bit values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sbunzini and @stdob-- I found the solution:

Schema:

```
type Activity{
  year: String
  countdocs: Int
}

type Query {
    totalActivityOverTime: [Activity] @cypher(statement: """
       MATCH (n:Document)
        RETURN { 
         year: n.year ,
         countdocs : COUNT(n) 
       }
    """) 
}
```

GraphQL:

```
{
  totalActivityOverTime{
    year
    countdocs 
  }
}
```

Thanks!